# Prove that $|\int_C f(z)dz| \le M |z_2 - z_1|$ where $M \gt 0$ such that $|f(z)|\le M; \ \forall \ z \in \Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be any two points in $\Omega$ and let $C$ be any oriented contour in $\Omega$ from $z_1$ to $z_2$. Also, assume that $f:\Omega \to \Bbb{C}$ is analytic on an open convex set $\Omega$, and $f(z)$ is bounded on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0):

We can think the contour $C:[0,1]\to \Omega$ such that 
$$
C(0)=z_1 \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ C(1)=z_2
$$
Define the path $\gamma: [0,1] \to \Omega$ by 
$$
\gamma(t) = (1-t)z_1 + t z_2
$$
Then clearly $\gamma(0)=C(0)$ and $\gamma(1)=C(1)$, since $\Omega$ is convex, this gives that $\gamma$ and $C$ are homotopic and then
$$
\int_Cf(z) dz = \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz
$$
Thus, by the $M.L$ inequality ([Estimation Lemma](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma)) 
$$
\left| \int_Cf(z) dz \right|= \left| \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz \right| \leq M \cdot Long(\gamma) = M |z_1 - z_2|
$$
as desired